# Gedit (from terminal) has stopped opening files in tabs, and now opens an instance per file - how do I switch it back to tabs?

Tags: ubuntu, mate-desktop, gedit

I'm using a new install of Ubuntu 12.04 MATE edition.  I'd installed gedit which had been working normally, ie if i did `gedit filename`, and gedit was already open, it opened the file in a new tab.

On friday, though, something weird happened and I was logged out.  When I logged back in, gedit now always opens a new instance when i do `gedit filename` from the terminal.  If I'm in Gedit, and open file using the menu, then it makes a new tab.

I did a reboot, and the problem persists.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?  I only ever want one Gedit open.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/79295, have a look at this answer.

Comment: Thanks - I saw that but it involves building your own version of gedit, which I'd rather not do if I can help it.  Given that it used to do the desired behaviour, I'd prefer to just find out what the change is and undo it if possible.